# Excel Export not accepting thousands separator

Tags: php, html, excel

I have this build up HTML table that I want to convert into Excel spreadsheet but it happens to show the amount thousands separator and the 2 decimal as the PHP function number_format specifies. in short like for 100.00 in Excel I am having 100

```
$OutputExcel = "
      <h3 align='center'>$COMPANYNAME</h3>
      <table class='tblNemoList' border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' width='100%' style='-fs-table-paginate: paginate;'> 
         <caption align='left'><b>Detailed Horse Charges</b></caption>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th align='left'>#</th>
               <th align='left'>No</th>
               <th align='left'>Horse Name</th>
               <th align='left'>Description</th>
               <th align='left'>Date</th>
               <th align='left'>Amount</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
   ";
   $i = 0;
   while($row = $xdb->fetch_object($rowHorseCharges))
   {
      //ini
      $i++;

      $OutputPDF .= "
         <tr >
            <td>$i</td>
            <td>".$row->No."</td>
            <td>".$row->strHorse."</td>
            <td>".$row->Description."</td>
            <td>".$row->Date."</td>
            <td align='right'>".number_format($row->Amount,2,'.',',')."</td>
         </tr>
      ";
      $OutputExcel .= "
         <tr >
            <td align='left' >$i</td>
            <td align='left' >".$row->No."</td>
            <td align='left' >".$row->strHorse."</td>
            <td align='left' >".$row->Description."</td>
            <td align='left' >".$row->Date."</td>
            <td align='right' >".number_format($row->Amount,2,'.',',')."</td>
         </tr>
      ";
   }
   $OutputPDF .= "
      <tr><td colspan='6' style='border-bottom:1px solid black;'></td></tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td align='right' ><b>Tota: ".number_format($rowTotal->Total,2,'.',',')."</b></td>
      </tr>
   </table>";

   $OutputExcel .= "
      <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td align='right' ><b>Total: ".number_format($rowTotal->Total,2,'.',',')."</b></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  ";
```

I am converting it using this

```
 switch($Action){
              case "Clear":
                 break;

              case "Export Excel":
                 include_once("reports/". $_REQUEST[radReport] .".php");
                 header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload");
                 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $strFilename .".xls"); //gets set inside the report.rpt.php
                 header("Pragma: no-cache");
                 header("Expires: 0");

                   echo $OutputExcel;
                   die;

                 break;

              case "ExportPDF":
                 include_once("reports/". $_REQUEST[radReport] .".php");
                 ini_set('display_errors', '0');
                 header("Content-type: application/pdf");

                 require_once('includes/mpdf/mpdf.php');
                 $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', $format ,9,'Arial');
                 $mpdf->setHTMLHeader(getPDFHeader($COMPANYNAME));
                 $mpdf->setHTMLFooter(getPDFFooter());
                 if($orientation == 'P'){$mpdf->AddPage($orientation,'', '' ,'','',15,15,20,16,7,9);}else{$mpdf->AddPage($orientation,'', '' ,'','',30,30,30,30,18,12);}
                 $mpdf->WriteHTML($OutputPDF);
                 $mpdf->Output($strFilename."pdf", "I");

                 die;
              break;

              case "OpenPDF":
              default:
                    $page->Content .= $Output
                    . js("d('". $_POST[radReport] ."').click(function())");
                break;
           }
```

Comment: How do you want to format the results?

Comment: You are using the dot as a decimal seperator. So `100.00` and `100` represent the same value. You need somehow to inform Excel that you want two visible digits behind the decimal point. Is it money?

Comment: I want it to display like this 100.00 for 100

Comment: and 2,345.00 for 2345 no it is not money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add CSS to your table page. Like so:

```
<style  type='text/css'>
  .num2d {
    mso-number-format:"0\.00";
  }
</style>
```

and then use that as a class to the `<td>` like so:

```
<td class="num2d">34</td>
```

I didn't make this up myself, but found it here:

http://cosicimiento.blogspot.nl/2008/11/styling-excel-cells-with-mso-number.html